# CSS grid column min of max-content and a fixed width

Tags: html, css, css-grid, min

I have a css grid for which I would like the column widths to be either the width of the largest item in that column or 100px, whichever is smaller. I thought `minmax(max-content, 100px)` might work but it doesn't. In the below example, the narrow column should be max-content (but is 100px) and the wide column should be 100px (but is max-content). Is it possible to do this with css grid?

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(max-content, 100px));
}

.element {
  background-color: lightblue;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="element">a</div>
  <div class="element">wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide</div>
  <div class="element">narrow</div>
  <div class="element">d</div>
  <div class="element">narrow</div>
  <div class="element">b</div>
  <div class="element">c</div>
  <div class="element">wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `max-width` on the item and keep the column auto width

```css
.table {
  display: grid;
  gap: 4px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, auto);
  justify-content: start; /* you need this to avoid the gap between column */
}

.element {
  background-color: lightblue;
  word-break: break-all;
  white-space: nowrap;
  max-width: 100px;
  /* hiding the overflow */  
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="element">a</div>
  <div class="element">wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide</div>
  <div class="element">narrow</div>
  <div class="element">d</div>
  <div class="element">narrow</div>
  <div class="element">b</div>
  <div class="element">c</div>
  <div class="element">wiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiide</div>
</div>
```